# Cleaning dupes and keeping max data

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that contains duplicates and I need to keep the max data and blow away the rest. Due to requirements I cannot change the date field format and I am getting a conversion error. Any ideas?

```
DELETE from MAIN_TBL
WHERE ID NOT IN 
(
select * from
(SELECT MAX(updated_on)
FROM MAIN_TBL
GROUP BY widget_tag, ID) as TEMP
)
```

ERROR = Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Think about the code you write. The derived table Temp contains a single column - the datatype of that column is datetime or similar. It contains multiple rows - which is probably a logic error but not a factor in the execution error. You then attempt to compare the column ID to this column in Temp. One of those columns is implicitly converted to the datatype of the other. Strings have very low precedence - so ID is converted into datetime. That is the source of your error.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to delete everything except newest rows per widget_tag you could use:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARITITION BY widget_tag ORDER BY updated_on DESC) rn
  FROM MAIN_TBL
)
DELETE FROM cte WHERE rn <> 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use EXISTS:

```
DELETE t
from MAIN_TBL t
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM MAIN_TBL
  WHERE id = t.id and widget_tag = t.widget_tag and updated_on > t.updated_on
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=faf678a5d2ad194a8ac80ed7b7628db8).